# Texture showing Inverted Image

Tags: opengl, box2d, glut, texture-mapping, texture2d

I have a Physics body that is a PolygonShape. The problem is when I am applying texture on it it shows inverted image! I am unable to figure out why? I guess I am giving the right pixel coordinates but still it doesn't work.
Here is the opengl rendering:

```
void drawSquare2(b2Vec2* points,b2Vec2 center,float angle) 
{

    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    glPushMatrix();

        pix.readBMPFile("marioStanding.bmp",1);
    pix.setChromaKey(255, 255, 255);        
    pix.setTexture(11);
            glTranslatef(center.x*M2P,center.y*M2P,0);
            glRotatef(angle*180.0/3.141,0,0,1);



    glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,11);


    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    int i=0;
            glVertex2f(points[i].x*M2P,points[i].y*M2P);
    glTexCoord2f(0,0);

    i++;
             glVertex2f(points[i].x*M2P,points[i].y*M2P);
    glTexCoord2f(0,1);


    i++;
            glVertex2f(points[i].x*M2P,points[i].y*M2P);
    glTexCoord2f(1,1);

        i++;
            glVertex2f(points[i].x*M2P,points[i].y*M2P);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0);



            glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

And this is how I am calling it from my `Display` Function

```
  for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
  points[i]=((b2PolygonShape*)tom_char->GetFixtureList()->GetShape())->GetVertex(i);

  drawSquare2(points,tom_char->GetWorldCenter(),tom_char->GetAngle());
```

`addRect` Logic:

```
b2Body* addRect2(int x,int y,int w,int h,bool dyn=true)
{
    b2BodyDef bodydef;  
    bodydef.position.Set(x*P2M,y*P2M);   //Setting body position
    if(dyn)
    {
            bodydef.type=b2_dynamicBody;  // dynamic body means body will move

    }

    b2Body* body=world->CreateBody(&bodydef);        //Creating box2D body

    b2PolygonShape shape;            //Creating shape object
    shape.SetAsBox(P2M*w,P2M*h);

    ////////////// Adding Fixtures(mass, density etc) //////////////

    b2FixtureDef fixturedef;
    fixturedef.shape=&shape;
    fixturedef.density=0.0;
    fixturedef.restitution = 0.7;
    body->CreateFixture(&fixturedef);
    return body;
}
```

and these are the parameters given to addRect:

```
tom_char=addRect(500,460,50,70,true);
```

Cannot spot where am I going wrong!

Comment: It is impossible to say given the little information you have provided. But I suspect you are not aware that the point (0,0) in normalized texture coordinates corresponds to the bottom-left corner of the texture image. (0,1) is the top-left, (1,1) is the top-right and (1,0) is the bottom-right.

Comment: And the order for polygons and Quads are (0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0) to map texture.

Comment: What more information u need??

Comment: For starters, the values of `points [0]` - `points [3]`. If the polygon starts at the top and is wound counter-clockwise then you have the wrong T coordinates.

Comment: So what should be the TexCoords??

Comment: Like I said, it is impossible to say without knowing how your polygon is wound. But if it is wound like I described previously then you should swap the 2nd component of each coordinate. (e.g. 1 becomes 0, and 0 becomes 1).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: It worked! Yes the vertices of the polygon are wounded counterclockwise! And swapping the coordinates solved the problem. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[PROBLEM SOLVED]**

Yes the vertices of the polygon are wounded counterclockwise! And swapping the coordinates solved the problem i.e the order should be (0,1),(0,0),(1,0),(1,1)

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot spot where am I going wrong!

You're doing wrong nothing. OpenGL using the usual transformations just puts the origin of images in the lower left rather the upper left. BTW, DIB/.bmp files support either ordering. If the `height` field in the header is a negative value, the origin of the image is in the lower left.

Essentially it boils down to know, where the image file places its origin, and where the origin of images is on the OpenGL side.

It's perfectly possible to change the way images are addressed in OpenGL, placing the origin in the upper left.